# How to make textView in Android as flexible as shown in image?

Tags: android, textview, height, wrapper

When the arrow of bottom left side is moved the text inside the box get rearranged:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. Would showing some code or configuration help readers understand what you are having trouble with?

Comment: @halfer I want to create dynamic TextView please see this image I want to create similar to it https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/_L_lGq9aimxAcloQH0eWTuUHsd4lw_kOFxv9aAhmdL1RNSOgFFdZvzrwoznwuWW6dg=h310-rw